# Javascript nested destructuring syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, destructuring

While I understand the normal ES6 destructuring syntax, how does the below nested syntax work?

```
const { get, set, computed, Logger: { debug, log } } = Ember;
```

Answer (score 3):

The property (referencing an object) on the left of the `:` is what the properties on the right, inside the `{}`s, are extracted from. So

```
const { get, set, computed, Logger: { debug, log } } = Ember;
```

is equivalent to

```
const { get, set, computed, Logger } = Ember;
const { debug, log } = Logger;
```

without the intermediate variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot...Just a quick question - so to understand, it is the same rule which is applied even for the nested/deep objects

Comment: Yep, the same rule applies for every occurrence of `key: { prop1, prop2 }` at *any* nesting level of the object

Comment: Cool...So in effect for the nested ones, they actually refer to Ember.Logger.log & Ember.Logger.debug 

Would that be correct ?

Comment: Yes, that's right